# LaTeX Overwriting colored text

Tags: color

In LaTeX, usually I use

> default color {\color{blue}changed color.}

[image]

or

> default color \textcolor{blue}{changed color.}

to change the color of a certain part of the text. Now I want to change the color of the whole sentence to a determined color, say red, as follows

[image]

I tried

> \textcolor{red}{default color {\color{blue}changed color.}}

but it just has effect on the uncolored text:

[image]

For certain reasons, I need to keep "\textcolor{blue}{changed color.}" in the origial text. Is there any way of overwritting the colored text?

Comment: It is not clear, what is your problem. This works: `\color{red}
default color \textcolor{blue}{changed color}. default color again`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Building upon [David Carlisle's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/573096/38080), you can define a macro that will be even nestable (is that a word?) ---

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\absolutetextcolor}[2]{%
    \textcolor{#1}{%
        \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
    #2}%
}

\begin{document}

\absolutetextcolor{red}{default color {\color{blue}changed color.}}

\absolutetextcolor{red}{default color {\absolutetextcolor{blue}{changed color.}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works nicely!

Comment: `\renewcommand{\color}[2][]{\ignorespaces}` would be better.

Comment: @egreg yes, you're 100% right

Answer (score 6):

It would be much better not to add the nested color or to add it as a locally defined command such as `\mycolor` that you could define to be a color, or nothing in different places, but if you really need this you can locally define `\color` to do nothing.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}

\textcolor{red}{\renewcommand\color[2][]{}default color {\color{blue}changed color.}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @campa well as I say, I wouldn't do this at all or better to use a custom command, so hopefully if this form is used you have a pretty good idea what is in that scope and not accepting arbitrary input and need "just in case" safety. But yes it would be safer, I'll update..

Answer (score -2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    default color {\color{blue}changed color.}\\
    \textcolor{red}{default color {\color{blue}changed color.}}\\
    \textcolor{red}{default color {changed color.}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's `tikz` for?

Comment: This does not answer the question, the OP asks to keep the `\color{blue}` in the last line (but have the output red)

Comment: @campa auto load color

Comment: My point is that loading the whole `tikz` package just to use `\color` is a wee bit extreme.