# Extra space when using (re)newcommand

Tags: macros, white-space

I have examined [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/573088/latex-overwriting-colored-text), where the OP wanted to discard the effect of `\color` when it is used inside an other `\textcolor`. @Rmano was faster than me and [answered the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/573099/100231) with the same way that I wanted.

However, "our" solution has a little problem about an extra whitespace:

[image: output]

I have tried to fix it many ways like `\relax`, `\gobble`, `\xspace` `\ignorespaces`, but I was shooting randomly and couldn't find the solution. Do you have any ideas?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}

\newcommand{\Textcolor}[2]{%
\textcolor{#1}{\renewcommand{\color}[1]{}#2}%
}%

\begin{document}
Some text

Some {\color{blue} text}

Some \textcolor{blue}{text}

\textcolor{red}{Some {\color{blue} text}}

\Textcolor{red}{Some {\color{blue} text}} %should produce the same

\Textcolor{red}{Some {\color{blue}text}} %should produce the same

\textcolor{red}{Some {\color{blue} text}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related question, [spacing - Extra space added after equation when it is coloured - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91536/extra-space-added-after-equation-when-it-is-coloured)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard working of `\color` ends with `\ignorespaces`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}

\newcommand{\Textcolor}[2]{%
  \textcolor{#1}{\renewcommand{\color}[1]{\ignorespaces}#2}%
}

\begin{document}

Some text

Some {\color{blue} text}

Some \textcolor{blue}{text}

\textcolor{red}{Some {\color{blue} text}}

\Textcolor{red}{Some {\color{blue} text}} %should produce the same

\Textcolor{red}{Some {\color{blue}text}} %should produce the same

\textcolor{red}{Some {\color{blue} text}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It should actually be

```
\renewcommand{\color}[2][]{\ignorespaces}
```

to cope with cases such as `\color[rgb]{0.1,1,0.3}`.

Comment: Thanks, it works :) You should leave a comment at the original question https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/573099/100231 I don't want to take your merits.